# Meanings of "big time"

Tags: idioms

## Scene 1 from the movie Big Trouble

> 00:34:04 I'm not long for this place.
>
> 00:34:06 my brother's working security at the airport.
>
> 00:34:09 **Big time.**
>
> 00:34:10 Oh, yeah. Check this out.
>
> 00:34:13 Well, we're not supposed to carry guns.

## Scene 2 from Rocky

> 01:18:32 One call from me, you're a celebrity.
>
> 01:18:36 - You need exposure. - Don't breathe on me, Paulie.
>
> 01:18:39 That's the **big time**... I know about these things.
>
> 01:18:42 - What do these guys want from me, huh? - To watch you train.
>
> 01:18:45 Hey, what is the matter with you? This is private.

## Scene 3 from Rags

> 00:57:54 But this is the Rags guy from the party last night.
>
> 00:57:56 Kadee, i am the guy that's always looking for the next best thing.
>
> 00:57:59 But clearly Rags isn't ready for the **big time**, or else he wouldn't ran out like he did.
>
> 00:58:03 Besides, i'm more concern about you.
>
> 00:58:06 Irma tells me you've been missing meetings.

All these conversations involve **big time**. I don't think it's used here for emphasizing how extreme or severe something is. Right?

Can you please walk me through these?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/big_time : The highest, or most prestigious level in any field, especially in entertainment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jim mentioned, 2 of the uses (Scene 2 and Scene 3) refer to a prestigious level of play. For instance, the "big leagues" usually refers to professional sports (and usually baseball in the United States).  This is the same as the usage of "big time".

For the usage in scene 1, it is ambiguous and difficult to tell what the usage is given a lack of context about the conversation.  Based just on the lines you wrote, it would imply "extreme" or "severe" in a way that is used to emphasize the impact of a statement.

For example: "If you don't do your homework, mother is going to yell at you big time!"

Notice that scene 2 and 3 have the article "the" immediately before "big time" as compared to scene 1 where there is no article before "big time".